# How can i check if input is a number ? If its a string alert an error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I press Send button, I want to check if the input is a number between 1 - 30.
 And if its not a number  alert and error.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="formFlow">

       <label for="level">Level:</label>
       <input type="text" name="level" id="level" class="difborder1" />

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what you’ve already tried.

Comment: use javascript and php validation

Comment: Please google these kinds of questions or atleast search within SO before posting. There is a lot of information about this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jquery solution:

you can on submit check if the input is an int using  `$.isNumeric()`

if no than display the error message and u have to disable the form submission so you can use `preventDefault()` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#check_label').click(function (e){
      if($.isNumeric($('#level').val()) && $('#level').val() >=1 && $('#level').val() <=30) { alert("Ok");}
      else{
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("error");
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="formFlow">

       <label for="level">Level:</label>
       <input type="text" name="level" id="level" class="difborder1" value="" />
       <input type="submit" id="check_label" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanx Everyone for your help , next time i will google deeper.This might work @Amani

Answer (score 1):

You can use this It's a simple validation in javascript

```js
function validate(){
  var level_chk = document.formFlow.level.value;
  if(isNaN(level_chk)|| level_chk > 30){
  alert("write whatever you want");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="formFlow" name="formFlow" onsubmit="validate();">

       <label for="level">Level:</label>
       <input type="text" name="level" id="level" class="difborder1" />
       <input type="submit" name="btnsub" id="btnsub">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `html 5` input:

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="Q2age" id="Q2age" size="10" min="18" max="99" pattern="[1-8][0-9]" required>
  <button type="submit" class="button" id="test">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's a code snippet:

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="Q2age" id="Q2age" size="10" min="18" max="99" pattern="[1-8][0-9]" required>
  <button type="submit" class="button" id="test">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Or Use Jquery Validate Js its better

Comment: A HTML5 form input would do just fine

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP when it receives a POST request for example.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['level'])
{
   if (!is_numeric($_POST['level']))
   {
      echo 'Error, the number is not numeric !';
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: HTML5 or JS would be more recommend

Answer (score 0):

in your form just use

```
<input type="number" name="nome" value="0">
```